# where does maven store the plugins after downloading?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Is it also in the .M2\repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Everything is stored in that directory.  Maven plugins retrieved from repositories are treated just like any other artifact.